# Remote control using ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, linux-mint

Given:

- 2 clients (A and B) on seperate private IP-nets without ssh-server but access to internet
- 1 server on a public IP with ssh-server

Wanted:

- control client A from client B

Restrictions:

- only use pre-installed software from LinuxMint 17

Guess:

- use some obscure features of ssh and screen

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, to achieve this you **require ssh-server to be installed on client A** in addition to the existing configuration. Linux Mint by default does not come with ssh-server installed. So it may not be possible in your case.

If you can install ssh-server on Client A, then you can set up SSH Reverse Tunneling as mentioned in [this link](http://juliansimioni.com/blog/2014/02/10/howto-access-a-linux-machine-behind-a-home-router-with-ssh-tunnels/)